# How do I split a comma-separated list of URLs into individual iFrames? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to figure out how to split a comma-separated list of URLs within the "src" attribute, and have each of the URL in their own iFrame. The application I'm using does not permit more than one iFrame element, so I was wondering if there was a way via **JavaScript** or **jQuery** to accomplish this.

The current syntax:

```
<iframe name="target" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/111,https://www.youtube.com/embed/222" width="100%" height="100" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
<iframe name="target" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/111" width="100%" height="100" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe name="target" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/222" width="100%" height="100" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Remember to search on Google or on SO for solutions before you ask, some questions has very easy-to-find solutions, like this search result:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=split+comma+separated+string+javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
// Iframe element with a placeholder for src property.
var urlTemplate = '<iframe name="target" src="{0}" width="100%" height="100" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>'

// Get both youtube sources and add to array. 
var sources = $('iframe').attr('src').split(',')

// Loop through the links in sources and append a video iframe to the output div.
for (var i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    $('.output').append(urlTemplate.replace('{0}', sources[i]));
}
```

You'll also need to hide the original element as it doesn't have a valid src.

https://jsfiddle.net/xotjjk9e/1/